# Structure Pointer Increment/Decrement c++

Tags: c++, pointers, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation, decrement

I have a pointer to a structure in c++.  I increment it.  When I decrement the pointer it does not return to the original address.  Would you please explain why it does not return to the original address when I decrement it?  Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
#include    <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct  __attribute__((__packed__)) theStructure
{
    int boop;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Integer stuff
    int intArray[27];
    int *ptrMyInts;

    ptrMyInts = intArray;
    cout << " The int address: " << ptrMyInts << endl;
    
    ptrMyInts++;
    cout << " The int address: " << ptrMyInts << endl;

    ptrMyInts--;
    cout << " The int address: " << ptrMyInts << endl << endl << endl;


    // Structure stuff
    struct  theStructure    *ptrMyStructure;
    
    ptrMyStructure = new theStructure;
    cout << " The structure address: " << ptrMyStructure << endl;

    ptrMyStructure++;
    ptrMyStructure = new theStructure;
    cout << " The structure address: " << ptrMyStructure << endl;

    ptrMyStructure--;
    cout << " The structure address: " << ptrMyStructure << endl;
    
    return(0);
}
```

This code yields the following results:

```
The int address: 0xbebee52c
The int address: 0xbebee530
The int address: 0xbebee52c


The structure address: 0x1f6d460
The structure address: 0x1f6d470
The structure address: 0x1f6d46c
```

I'm not sure why when decremented the structure is 0x1f6d46c intstead of the original 0x1f6d460.

Comment: `ptrMyStructure = new theStructure;` you change the pointer **completely** between the increment and the decrement!

Comment: Cut and paste error presumably. Sometimes you just need to properly look at the code you have written.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new `MyStructure` and overwriting the original pointer. The overwritten pointer is then decremented, which creates a new pointer value that's illegal -- it's neither pointing to an object not to the address exactly after an object. Try removing the second line:

```
ptrMyStructure = new theStructure;
```

Then the decrement of the pointer value should result in the same address as the original address obtained from the first call to `new`.

Comment: undefined? I think there is UB in the code but what do you mean?

Comment: You're decrementing a pointer to a freshly created structure. The resulting decremented pointer is "undefined" in the sense that you cannot do anything safe with it: it doesn't point to anything valid.

Comment: ok then I was refering to the same, because incrementing the pointer is ok afaik (only once and not dereferencing it). Maybe add the comment to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain your code. Firstly, you allocated a memory block for `theStructure`

```
struct  theStructure    *ptrMyStructure;
ptrMyStructure = new theStructure;       // ptrMyStructure == 1
```

now `ptrMyStructure` pointed to address `1`. Then you increased `ptrMyStructure` by one

```
ptrMyStructure++;                        // ptrMyStructure == 2
```

now it pointed to address `2`. Secondly, you allocated another memory block for `theStructure` then made `ptrMyStructure` pointed to it (for example, address `5`) without `del` the first one (`1`)

```
ptrMyStructure = new theStructure;       // ptrMyStructure == 5
```

Now, you decreased `ptrMyStructure` by one, `ptrMyStructure` pointed to `4`

```
ptrMyStructure--;                        // ptrMyStructure == 4
```

[image: Memory layout, for example]

Comment: "enter image description here" is an instruction for you to follow. Currently, your answer discriminates against a good chunk of people.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it, can you explain about discrimination ? Btw, I filled up [enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the increments, you are on a 32 bit system.

When you do the following :

```
>    // Structure stuff
>     struct  theStructure    *ptrMyStructure;
>     
>    ptrMyStructure = new theStructure;
>    cout << " The structure address: " << ptrMyStructure << endl;
```

This means that a block of memory of size int is at address 0x1f6d460

```
>    ptrMyStructure++;
>    ptrMyStructure = new theStructure;
```

You incremented the address by 32 bits (4 bytes) but then reallocated it and the block is now at the address 0x1f6d470.

So when you do

```
>    ptrMyStructure--;
```

You decrement your address by 32 bits (4 bytes) so the address of the pointer is now 0x1f6d46c

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help!

I did not realize that it was unnecessary (and incorrect) to use new

The suggestion from John Källén

"Try removing the second line:

ptrMyStructure = new theStructure;

"
Resolved the issue.

I'm always learning new things... It's a never-ending process.

Thanks!